# How to ignore CODEOWNERS on dev to master PR?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, github-codeowners

We are trying to automatically add our DevOps group as default PR reviewers whenever a PR to master is opened.

For this purpose, we have created a CODEOWNERS file in the master branch and added our DevOps group as reviewers.
If we create a CODEOWNERS file in the dev branch, in which we will not specify our DevOps group as reviewers but the dev team instead (We only need DevOps for master), any time a PR from dev to master will be opened the CODEOWNERS would be overwritten on merge.

How can we prevent overwriting the CODEOWNERS file on PRs?